# function like __construct function but for specific function on LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

function like __construct function but for specific function.

my route

```php
Route::resource('form00', 'Form00Controller');
Route::resource('form001', 'Form001Controller');
........ and more
```

my __contsruct in Form00Controller

```php
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'projectName' => 
                array(
                    'required',
                    'regex:/(^([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)?$)/u'
                )
        ];
    }
```

my another Form00Controller function

```php
    public function create()// this function and another not effected
    {
        return view('form00.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)//__construct just for this function
    {

        $requestData = $request->all();

        Form00::create($requestData);

        return redirect('form00')->with('flash_message', 'Form00 added!');
    }
```

i need validate just for function store and not change that function.

Comment: Why do you need a construct in a Controller? Please help me understand your expected result.

Comment: @AndrésHernández whats wrong with having a construct in a Controller? Are you referring to the OP's construct, or just in general?

Comment: @AndrésHernández i need add validate just for function store and not change that function.

Comment: @AdityaThakur You can use a construct in the controller, but I see no need to do it here.

Comment: that is create a row to db (just ignore it)

Comment: my question is only for what functions like __construct

Comment: but it for specific function not all.

Comment: Why uh need construct for validation , construct will execute everytime uh hit any controller method. lets say you hit get request , now in get there is no `ProjectName`, thats mean its going you throw validation error, even when uh no need it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the perfect example for Custom Form Requests you can follow this [tutorial](https://rfmeier.net/creating-custom-form-request-laravel/)

Basically you'll end up with

```
public function store(StoreFormFormRequest $request)//__construct just for this function
    {

        $requestData = $request->all();

        Form00::create($requestData);

        return redirect('form00')->with('flash_message', 'Form00 added!');
    }
```

And you'll have a `StoreFormFormRequest` class into `app/Http/Requests` which will be something like

```
class StoreFormFormRequest extends FormRequest {

    public function rules() {
        return [
            'projectName' => 'required|regex:/(^([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)?$)/u'
        ]    
    }
}
```

Validation will be triggered automatically and, if it passes, the controller's code will be executed.

Comment: I have to write where it is ?, because there is no file called app/Http/Requests

Comment: For a better understanding, you should refer to the documentation, here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests